# How can I turn this into a two-column layout within the list element?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

```
<ul>
<a href="/blah"><li><img src='/profile.jpg'><span>Name</span><span>Address</span></li></a>
</ul>
```

I want to have two columns with the image in the left column spanning two rows and the text in the right column on an upper and lower row to the right of the image.

I tried using divs with blueprint css but then the anchor tag is displayed in a weird way - it doesn't appear to encompass the entire list element on hover but instead a sliver.

I also tried with a table layout but because I can't control the padding well with CSS it looks bulky.

How can I turn this into a two-column layout within the list element?

Answer (score 1):

Some of your HTML is invalid, so I've taken the liberty of cleaning some of it up.  Something like this should work for you:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <span class="item-container"><a href="/blah"><img src="blah.jpg" /></a></span>
            <div class="item-container">
                <span class="item">Name</span>
                <span class="item">Address</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.item {float:left; clear:left;}
.item-container {float:left;}
```

Add margins/padding as necessary.

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/KUaCE/

Answer (score 0):

use `float:left` on all elements,  also needs float for proper height